# getting emails of people who have not posted in more than 1 week

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following problem.

People post tasks on the site.

All the tasks that people post go into the task table with following structure:

```
id
user_id
date_posted
```

and there is a user table with the following table

```
id
first_name
email
```

I need to get the emails of people who have not posted tasks for more than a week? how can I do that? I tried the following:

```
SELECT distinct u.id, u.email FROM user as u WHERE id IN (SELECT user_id FROM task WHERE paid = 1 AND DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -7 DAY) <= `date_posted` AND `date_posted` < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -6 DAY)) AND role = 0
```

but I don't think that is the right way to go. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT u.id, u.email 
FROM user as u WHERE id NOT IN ( /* select users who posted */
  SELECT distinct user_id FROM task 
  WHERE paid = 1 AND DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) <= `date_posted` 
) AND role = 0;
```

Not tested but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT DISTINCT u.id, u.email
FROM (
        SELECT t.user_id AS user_id
        FROM task t
        WHERE DATE(t.date_posted) > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)
    ) AS t
RIGHT JOIN USER u ON u.id = t.user_id
WHERE t.user_id IS NULL
```